# Visual Connect Wall: Heads up!

Tags: visual, connect-wall

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7045/60644)</sup>

---

**Rules:** Organize the following sixteen images into four groups of four, based on categories into which they fit. The sixteen images are also connected by one overarching theme.

(Bonus points if you can not only find the categories, but fully name everything.)

[image]

Hint to start you off:

> One of the categories is something you'd find in the Senate, or on certain animals.

Hint #2:

> The four groups could be considered as four general "types" of the overarching theme.

[Google Drive link to a bigger version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J3ziAE799qrxr-G5tO-QP3G7BHNp_ncn/view?usp=sharing), for my fellow visually impaired people.

Comment: I see two or maybe even three things in the second-leftmost picture on the bottom row. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overarching theme of this connecting wall is:

> **HEADWEAR** (hence the title).

Specifically, the 16 images can be described as (left to right, top to bottom):

> POLICE, [BUDENOVKA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budenovka), the [HOMBURG](https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/heraldrywiki/index.php?title=Homburg_(Saarland)) coat-of-arms, PORK PIE;
>  [PAPAKHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papakha), COAL MINERS, [The FEDORA Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fedora_Project), [Old Dominion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Dominion_(band)) (country music band who recorded the track '[SNAPBACK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLQATzCyxfE)');
>  [USHANKA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushanka), FIREFIGHTERS, the [STORMY KROMER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormy_Kromer_cap) logo, TRUCKER;
>  [USS TRILBY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Trilby_(SP-673)), BASEBALL, HARD HAT (construction worker), [ASTRAKHAN](https://russianlegacy.com/astrakhan-hats-c-45_314_324.html)

These can be separated into the following 4 categories:

> 1. **HELMETS** (used in the workplace) - POLICE helmet, COAL MINER'S helmet, FIREFIGHTER'S helmet, HARD HAT (construction worker's helmet).
>
>  2. **HATS FROM RUSSIA/CAUCASUS COUNTRIES** - BUDENOVKA, PAPAKHA, USHANKA, ASTRAKHAN.
>
>  3. **SOFT/FELT HATS** - [TRILBY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilby), [HOMBURG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homburg_hat), [PORK PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork_pie_hat), [FEDORA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora).
>
>  4. **CAPS** - BASEBALL cap, [STORMY KROMER cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormy_Kromer_cap), [TRUCKER/NETBACK cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trucker_hat), [SNAPBACK](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/snapback).

Comment: [Note that SP 673 is also rot13(gur zbqry ahzore bs n fxv pnc).](https://suburbanskiandbike.com/Eisbar-Star-Neon-Pompon-MU-SP-673-E403336-673/) But I suspect your interpretation of it is the intended one.

Comment: This is indeed the intended solution, well done! Just one note: the Old Dominion clue was intended to clue their most famous song, "Snapback." :)

Comment: @Sciborg Aha, that was knowledge I didn't have! Correction made, thanks :)